# Getting a sql exception due to a fk constraint for unknown reasons

Tags: sql, vb.net, t-sql, stored-procedures

SO the exact error message I'm getting is:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_featuredtype_featured". The conflict occurred in database
>   "docphin", table "dbo.featured", column 'featuredID'. The statement
>   has been terminated."

The part of my vb code that calls the sp that has the insert statement is:

```
If isChanged1.Checked Then
    lq.admin_RemoveFeatured(isChanged.featuredID1)
    lq.admin_AddFeatured(title1.Text, text1.Text, imageURL1.Text, login1.Checked, index1.Checked, mobile1.Checked, Integer.Parse(priority1.Text))

End If

If isChanged2.Checked Then
    lq.admin_RemoveFeatured(isChanged.featuredID2)
    lq.admin_AddFeatured(title2.Text, text2.Text, imageURL2.Text, login2.Checked, index2.Checked, mobile2.Checked, Integer.Parse(priority2.Text))

End If
```

Now the odd thing is when I execute admin_AddFeatured in sql server it works fine.

admin_RemoveFeatured:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[admin_RemoveFeatured] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @featuredID int
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    delete from featuredtype where featuredID= @featuredID
    delete from featured where featuredID= @featuredID


END

GO
```

admin_AddFeatured:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[admin_AddFeatured] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @title varchar(500) , 
    @text varchar(MAX),
    @imageURL varchar(200),
    @loginPage bit,
    @indexPage bit,
    @mobilePage bit,
    @priority int
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

         -- Insert statements for procedure here
        insert into featured
        (title,text,imageURL, priority )
        values
        (@title,@text,@imageURL, @priority)

        insert into featuredtype
        (loginPage, indexPage, mobilePage)
        values
        (@loginPage, @indexPage, @mobilePage)


END

GO
```

I've been at this testing different solutions but I can't really seem to grasp what might be wrong here. My only thought is that ic could be related to how I get the ID field for each "feature" items that i'm inserting of deleting. For that I made a module:

```
Public Module isChanged
    Public featuredID1 As Integer
    Public featuredID2 As Integer
    Public featuredID3 As Integer
    Public featuredID4 As Integer
    Public featuredID5 As Integer
    Public featuredID6 As Integer
End Module
```

Then, in the page load sub I use an sp and read in the ID, like:

```
   Dim lq2 As New lqDFDataContext
        Dim var = lq2.admin_GetFeatured().ToList()
        Dim i As Integer = 1

        For Each f In var
            If i = 1 Then
                isChanged.featuredID1 = f.featuredID
                title1.Text = f.title
                text1.Text = f.text
                imageURL1.Text = f.imageURL
                login1.Checked = f.loginPage
                index1.Checked = f.indexPage
                mobile1.Checked = f.mobilePage
                priority1.Text = Str(f.priority)
            End If

etc...
```

Answer (score 3):

You're not setting the `featuredID` in the `featuredType` table

try this

```
   select @featuredID = Scope_Identity()

   insert into featuredtype 
        (loginPage, indexPage, mobilePage,featuredID) 
        values 
        (@loginPage, @indexPage, @mobilePage, @featuredID)
```

Comment: It got rid of the error, but for some reason its not updating the db at all. It also might be worth mention that the code that gets the featuredID from the sp is in the pageload sub and the other code I displayed is in a sub for a button click.

Comment: It appears new entries are being made into the db because the id's are changing, but the other values are not changing for some reason, ie. title, text, priority etc...

Comment: What happens if you run the SP from SQL Management studio? Do records get inserted? Does it give errors?

Comment: Figured out whats wrong. So when my page loads it fills the textboxes with the values of what is in the db. Then I wanted the user to be able to change values in these boxes, then they check a box to flag it as being changed. The problem is when I go to insert this into the db textbox.text is still equal to the value that was loaded into it in page load sub, rather than the new value typed in there. Is there a way to update textbox.text also I need to update checkbox values.

Comment: Is this a web app? Sounds like you're filling the text box on postback in Page_load

Comment: Yeah, this is an asp.net web page